# How to compare two variables that have first-order dependencies?

Tags: t-test, autoregressive

I have the following data,

```
Observ   X1    X2    X3    X4
1        20    60    90    140
2        30    30    80    170
3        40    80    120   190
4        10    70    90    90 
              ...
```

And it is known that $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ have only **first order** dependencies, even though it is not confirmed in my data.

Then, is it meaningless to directly compare (e.g. t-test) $X_1$ and $X_2$?

If so, is there any other option that I should consider?

Comment: What do you mean by first order dependency, and why would you want to do a $t$-test between two columns?